# getting current value reflection c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, connection-string

i have used the following code to change the current value for the current field value as

```
FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);  

connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);
```

but my query is to get current value of connectionstringfied...

i tried the below code as

```
getvalue(obj ss);
```

waiting for your valuable esponses

it throws me null values

Comment: Why are you attempting to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `connectionStringField` has found the field (i.e. it is in the base type and is called "_sqlConnectionString", then it should just be:

```
string connectionString = (string)connectionStringField.GetValue(this);
```

?

However, using reflection to talk to non-public fields is... unusual.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetPropertyValue<T>(this T obj, string parameterName)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] property = null;
        Type typ = obj.GetType();
        if (listPropertyInfo.ContainsKey(typ.Name))
        {
            property = listPropertyInfo[typ.Name];
        }
        else
        {
            property = typ.GetProperties();
            listPropertyInfo.TryAdd(typ.Name, property);
        }
        return property.First(p => p.Name == parameterName).GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
    }
```

listPropertyInfo is a cache to avoid reflection performance issue

Comment: caching a `PropertyInfo` doesn't really "avoid reflection performance issues" - the `GetValue` etc are still **really** slow (comparatively speaking). Also, using `.Name` as the lookup is dangerous - you should just use the type itself. The question is talking about private fields, not public properties - so this won't even work. But for something like the above, if you were *serious* about the performance issues, you'd have to do a lot of meta-programming - or just use something like FastMember that wraps all that up for you. Also: why does it return string? not everything is a string!

Comment: my case only need string, i post the extension method i use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(this T obj, string parameterName, object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] property = null;
        Type typ = obj.GetType();
        if (listPropertyInfo.ContainsKey(typ.Name))
        {
            property = listPropertyInfo[typ.Name];
        }
        else
        {
            property = typ.GetProperties();
            listPropertyInfo.TryAdd(typ.Name, property);
        }
        if (value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            value = null;
        }
        property.First(p => p.Name == parameterName).SetValue(obj,value, null);
    }
```

I used the same trick for setters